# 'PDOException' Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting the following error when trying to submit details of an order into my database:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/handlers/checkout-handler.php on line 111 PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_details, order_address, cust_id, cust_name, delivery_type, paid) ' at line 1.

I can't figure out whats wrong with it, all of the variables are being posted correctly to the page.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO order (order_details, order_address, cust_id, cust_name, delivery_type, paid) VALUES(:details,:address,:d,:name,:delivery,:paid);";                                         
$sql=$conn->prepare($query1);
$sql->bindParam(':details', $details);
$sql->bindParam(':address', $address);
$sql->bindParam(':name', $name);
$sql->bindParam(':delivery', $delivery_type);
$sql->bindParam(':paid', $paid);
$sql->bindParam(':d', $d);
$sql->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order` is a reserved keyword. You should add backticks `` ` `` around it to use it:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `order` (order_details, order_address, cust_id, cust_name, delivery_type, paid) 
           VALUES(:details,:address,:d,:name,:delivery,:paid);";                                         
$sql = $conn->prepare($query1);
```

See also : [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)